# In a stored procedure, how can I get the name of the sproc in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I want to dynamically get the name of the current stored procedure inside itself for logging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```